# Magento Test Automation Framework (MTAF)

Tags: php, magento, selenium, phpunit, mtaf

The magento site is setup on machineA. The test framework and selenium are setup on machineB. The tests works fine from machineB. But is it possible to run the test from another machineC or browser. This is actually for different testers to invoke and run the tests.

Has anybody tired out MTAF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MTAF works fine. It is possibel to run tests from machineC provided there is a node (Selenium) that is running. You can try different phpunit files and run different instances.
Example: 'runtests.sh mage:googlechrome:phpunit1.xml, enterprise:firefox, mage:firefox'  will execute 3 instances of tests at the same time from the same machine